# Python Asyncio: How to await something?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am having a hard time understanding asyncio and the await function. I have a script that uses the Telethon wrapper that requires me to understand / use asyncio.

The only goal of the script is to download an image from a Telegram group.

I have read a beginner asyncio tutorial but I am still having a very hard time understand the concept of it and how to await something.

```
# Start Client 
client1 = TelegramClient('sesh1', api_id1, api_hash1)
client1.start('xxx')
time.sleep(0.1)

# ---------------------------------------

# Get last message
for message in client1.iter_messages(groupname, limit=1):
    data = message.file
    print(data)
    # Download is last message is media
    if data is not None:
        print("Img found")
        x = client1.download_media(message=message)
        print(x)
```

The error I keep getting is:

> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'DownloadMethods.download_media' was never awaited.

How do I await the download function?

Comment: Just add `await` before `client1.download_media`: `x = await client1.download_media(message=message)`. You *do* need to place your code in a coroutine itself (so an `async def ...` function).

Comment: You may want to pick up a tutorial on asyncio first, like https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a read tonight!

Comment: When I turn it into a async function and change it to:  x = await client1.download_media(message=message)

It just changes the error to:
coroutine 'get_img' was never awaited
  get_img()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: You haven't shown us the code that calls `get_img`, so it's hard to help you, but presumably you have to await that one as well. The top-level coroutine must be run by a call to `asyncio.run()`. For more details refer to the asyncio tutorial that Martijn kindly provided.